# How to Show data from vertical to horizontal SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have some data

```
code         date        No_day
----         ----        -------
101         1/1/2015      30 
101         15/12/2015    45
101         14/02/2016    18
```

i want to show like this

```
code      date      No_day    date          No_day    date         No_day
----      ------    ------   ---------     -------    -------      -------
101      1/1/2015     30     15/12/2015      45     14/02/2016     18
```

Comment: It is called `Pivot`. Lookup for `Pivot/Cross tab` in `Sql Server`

Comment: You can just use PIVOT / UNPIVOT in sql: See here: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query

Comment: Thanks MR Sebastian Schulz and Mr Prdp  to answer